# ansible to restart network service

Tags: ansible

I copy-pasted this from the [manual](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html) and it fails in my playbook (version 2.0.2):

```
- service: name=network state=restarted args=eth0
```

I am getting this error:

```
"msg": "Failed to stop eth0.service: Unit eth0.service not loaded.\nFailed to start eth0.service: Unit eth0.service failed to load: No such file or directory.\n"}
```

What is the correct syntax, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per **Ansible 2.7.8**. You have to make following changes to restart the network.

> **Note**: I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04

***Scenario 1: Only network restart***

```
- name: Restarting Network to take effect new IP Address
  become: yes 
  service:
    name: networking
    state: restarted
```

***Scenario 2: Flush interface and then restart network***

```
- name: Flushing Interface
  become: yes
  shell: sudo ip addr flush "{{net_interface}}"

- name: Restarting Network
  become: yes 
  service:
    name: networking
    state: restarted
```

> **Note**: Make sure you have `net_interface` configured and then imported in the file where you execute this Ansible task.

**OUTPUT**

Please find below output that I received on my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just do like this (@nasr already commented it):

```
- name: Restart network
  service:
    name: network
    state: restarted
```

But if you change network configuration before restart, something like IP address, after restart ansible hangs because connection is lost (IP address changed).

Comment: Won't work if system does not have the "network" service. That applies to recent Fedora and RHEL 8, in particular. There, you can do the equivalent of `systemctl restart NetworkManager`. I am still looking for uniform Ansible solution.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do things right.

> tasks.yml

```
- name: net configuration step 1
  debug:
    msg: we changed some files
  notify: restart systemd-networkd

- name: net configuration step 2
  debug:
    msg: do some more work, but restart net services only once
  notify: restart systemd-networkd
```

> handlers.yml

```
- name: restart systemd-networkd
  systemd:
    name: systemd-networkd
    state: restarted
  async: 120
  poll: 0
  register: net_restarting

- name: check restart systemd-networkd status
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ net_restarting.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: async_poll_results
  until: async_poll_results.finished
  retries: 30
  listen: restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: I believe this answer with the use of async is the way to go.
And alternatively to the task `async_status` it's possible to have a task using `ansible.builtin.wait_for_connection` instead, for having the same result

Answer (score 4):

I m using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` that uses `systemd` instead of `init`

The following worked fine with me ( I tried the solutions mentioned earlier but none has worked for me)

```
  - name: restart network
    systemd:
      name: NetworkManager
      state: restarted
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- command: /etc/init.d/network restart
```

does work wonderfully but I feel that using `command` kinda defeats the purpose of using ansible.

Comment: Note that you have restarted all network service using `/etc/init.d/network restart` you can do the same with service module using `service: name=network state=restarted` just removing `args`